# download page/folder privacy with .htaccess?

Tags: security, .htaccess

I have a private folder on my domain like

http://example.com/protected

and i stored lot of images and pdf file there

```
 /protected/pad1.pdf
 /protected/pad2.pdf
 /protected/pad1.png
 /protected/pad1.png
```

supose these are the files, how can i hide or protect access to there files with the help of .htaccess file.

allow only users those who knows the password.

is it possible ???

Answer (score 5):

Check out Apache's page on [Authentication, Authorization and Access Control](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/auth.html) -- one method would be using Basic or Digest authentication. That would look something like this:

```
AuthType Digest
AuthName "Private files"
AuthDigestFile /usr/local/apache/passwd/digest
Require user (usernames here)
```

Of course, you need to generate a password and/or digest file using `htdigest` or `htpasswd` as well, but that procedure is explained in the document I linked to.

Answer (score 1):

Or for zero configuration and zero access:

```
Order Allow, Deny
Deny From All
```

=)

Comment: He wants to *hide* or protect. Why -1?

Comment: He said "allow only users those who knows the password" -- implying *someone* needs access to the files.

Comment: It's a perfectly valid answer. "Zero access" in this case means zero access through HTTP. You could set up FTP access to the folder to allow downloading of the files - although in that case you'd be better off moving them outside the web root...